# Windows 10 system tray reduce icons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have my Windows 10 taskbar displays all of the system tray icons, and i already set it all off in the control panel taskbar settings.

Is there a control somewhere where I can specify how many icons it can display?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, right-click on the *Notification* icon (looks like a cartoon word balloon) and select `Don't show app icons`.

Then:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>.
- Select `Customize the taskbar`.

[image: Customize the taskbar]

- Scroll down and click on `Select which icons appear on the taskbar`.

[image: Select which icons appear on the taskbar]

- If `Always show all icons on the taskbar` is `On`, then turn it off.
- Select which icons you want displayed.

If this does not work then it may be set through the Registry.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click `Yes` in the UAC dialog.
- Scroll to (or copy and paste in the location bar) 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer'.
- [Set](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-reghacks.html) `EnableAutoTray` to 1.
- Scroll to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
- If it does not exist, add the DWORD value `UseTabletModeNotificationIcons`: Right-click the right panel and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value`.
- Set `UseTabletModeNotificationIcons` to 0.

Finally, the [display of icons in the Notification Area can be set through Group Policy (GP)](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5313-hide-show-notification-area-icons-taskbar-windows-10-a.html). Since some versions of Windows don't provide a GP editor, the following Registry settings can be used.

- Scroll to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`.
- If the value `NoAutoTrayNotify` exists, [set it to 0 or delete it](https://www.windows-security.org/92129277e5a19c3e1d5a04658fce0e73/turn-off-notification-area-cleanup).
- Scroll to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`.
- If the value `NoAutoTrayNotify` exists, [set it to 0 or delete it](https://www.windows-security.org/92129277e5a19c3e1d5a04658fce0e73/turn-off-notification-area-cleanup).

It's a good thing MS gave us such a simple interface to the System Tray... oops, Notification Area.

Comment: i already set it to all off but it wasn't reacting to anything, and still displays everything

Comment: @brianff, Registry changes have been added that might help.