# Windows won't hide my notification area icons, even though I set them to hide

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, notification-area

In Windows 10, windows will always show all of my notification area icons.  I've went into "Taskbar Settings => Select which icons appear on the taskbar", and turned off everything, but all the icons still appear anyway. How do I get them to hide under the chevron icon like they normally do?

Comment: Related post - [Windows 10 system tray reduce icons](https://superuser.com/q/1352561/374397)

Answer (score 2):

Both of the following registry keys should have a DWORD called NoAutoTrayNotify. The DWORD's value should be 0.

1. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
2. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Windows 10 home version, we also could remove notification through the following group policy items:User > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > remove notification abd action center

Comment: That eliminates the notifications entirely. It doesn't hide them under the chevron icon.